# How to use arrays with Katalon recorder

Tags: arrays, katalon-recorder

I was trying to search an article which will simply explain how to use arrays with Katalon recorder and could not find a relevant one, and I combined a few examples into a working solution for myself. Sharing for anyone who needs it.

I tried googling and could not find a relevant solution.

Answer (score 0):

storeEval  new Array('a','b','c','d','e');  Arr
store   0         n
while   n<5 
storeEval  storedVars['Arr'][${n}]    row_value
echo   ${row_value} 
type   id=form_value      ${row_value}
storeEval  ${n}+1        n
endWhile

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).